# Light LED when 2 others are disconnected

Tags: led

I need to make circuit in which orange LED will light only when yellow and red are disconnected. When one of buttons is pushed orange LED should turn off.

See my attempt at it below.

I am new to electronics so your help is very appreciated.

[image: Fritzing diagram]

**EDIT:**

After many atemps I managed to build this circuit as on left side of schematic (tested on live breadboard)

[image: schematics]

but my primary goal is to make this work with RGB LED. I took Common Anode RGB LED for this and build circuit on right side of schematic. I do not have such RGB LED to test it live so I ask you to review if that schematic will work as it has few changes to one with 3 LED's. Thank you

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to Bruce's help my circuit now works.

3 separate LEDs emulate common anode RGB LED (as I do not have one to test circuit)
Q2 is BC 560B transistor with CBE type pinout

[image]

[image]

CODE:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(2,INPUT);
  pinMode(4,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(digitalRead(2));
  Serial.println(digitalRead(4));
}
```

Comment: I'm a newbie too, but are you planning on using an Arduino by any chance?

Comment: Yes I plan to use Arduino and using Arduino is easy way for that. But need this circuit because I need to have about 20 circuits like that and this make use of 60 arduino I/O's which I want to use for some other things than light this LED

Comment: By being disconnected, I'm assuming that you mean the buttons for the red and yellow LED's are not pressed down?

Comment: yes, when button is pressed LED is ON, when not pressed LED is OFF, when both(red, yellow) LED's are OFF orange LED should turn ON

Comment: I haven't done any of this myself, but I think you could use a MOSFET and hook up all the orange LED's to the drain pin. Have the Arduino read buttonState (google this). Then if the buttonState is LOW, meaning disconnected, have the Arduino digitalWrite HIGH to the gate of the MOSFET controlling the orange LED. If the buttonState is LOW, have the Arduino digitalWrite LOW to the gate. Just a general idea, although I'm sure there are better ways to do this.

Comment: I want to make this circuit without using Arduino. Using only electronic parts but I do not know which and how to connect that circuit.

Comment: I have edited my question with more details

Comment: I'd just use DPDT buttons instead.

Comment: I'm finding this statement self-contradictory: "orange LED will light only when yellow and red are disconnected. When one of buttons is pushed orange LED should turn off." "yellow *and* red" suggests I'd need to be pressing either both, or none (do the buttons disconnect when pressed? Or do they connect when pressed?), but then you say the orange LED goes off when just *one* button is pressed. Please clarify what you actually mean.

Comment: A [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) of every possible state, along with a clear description of exactly what the buttons should do (turn on or turn off the associated LEDs?) would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the green LED to be on *only* when the red and blue LEDs are both off. In other words, you want the voltage on the green LED to be LOW only when the voltages on the red and blue LEDs are both HIGH. That is a logical NAND function.

Your right-hand circuit with the RGB LED won't work because the transistor's collector is connected to the wrong place - it's shorting out the battery! Another problem is that the Arduino can only switch to Ground or +5V, so it can't replace a 'floating' switch.

You need a configuration that produces a logical NAND function. Your left-hand circuit is doing it, but won't work with a common anode RGB LED. So swap the transistor to a PNP  type, and add a couple of resistors to switch it on when either input goes low, like this:-

[image]

Comment: To clarify my goal for RGB LED ... when buttons are open (not pushed) Green LED should be OFF, when one of buttons are closed (pushed) certain LED (red or blue) should be ON and green should turn OFF

Comment: So when both buttons are open the green LED should be OFF, and when either button is closed the green LED should _also_ be OFF. When should the green LED be ON?

Comment: my bad english .... sorry Bruce ... correct "when buttons are open (not pushed) Green LED should be ON"

Comment: I have bought PNP transistor CTBC 560B (lowest voltage they had in store) and your circuit does not work with it. when I remove this transistor D3 (on your schematics) turns ONO. When I return it to circuit D3 turns OFF. I used R1,R2,R3 220ohm and R4,R5 10k ohm. Is it problem with resistors or with this transistor?

Comment: "when I remove this transistor D3 (on your schematics) turns OFF". If the transistor is removed the LED should be ON. If the transistor stays on when the switches are open then either it's connected the wrong way around, or noise is getting to its base through the wiring. You can put a 10k resistor from base to emitter to ensure that it turns off (this should not be problem when the switches are replaced with an Arduino, as R4 and R5 will be pulled high).

Comment: this is my breadboard and schematics based on your example: http://i.imgur.com/QYzJe9z.png http://i.imgur.com/7tt6VYs.png - my later goal is to replace switches with limit stop switches and read on arduino INs state of limit stop circuits (blue, red LEDs), green LED is indicator which is supposed to work without arduino connection.

Comment: BC560B connections are 1. Collector, 2. Base, 3. Emitter.

Comment: "my later goal is to replace switches with limit stop switches and read on arduino INs state of limit stop circuits". Enable pullups on Arduino inputs and it should be fine.

Comment: YAY it works :D thank you Bruce very much. you mean connecting after switch to arduino IN instead of GND?

Comment: Thanks Bruce again after some trial & error I managed to read state in arduino from this circuit. Your help was priceless.